# How do I set up an azure app service with the url of mysite.com/app1 and mysite.com/app2

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to set up an Azure AppServices in azure.  I have multiple apps that I want to run under the same domain and the url to be applied as such.  mysite.com/app1, mysite.com/app2, etc.  I know I can do this under IIS but I am wanting to use Azure AppServices instead of using a virtual server that I will have to manage.

Comment: The answer by @bruce below is great. However you might want to consider  just creating 2 different applications and sharing the app service plan

Comment: Could you please explain this.  As I have mentioned I am pretty familiar with IIS, which was one of the thing @bruce identified, but I am new to Azure and really plan to dig in.  However, I need to get this migration done and build upon my knowledge as I go.  I would agree that bruce has really provided a good answer, but would like to understand more of what you have suggested as well.

Comment: If you are starting out with App Service, I recommend this Microsoft Virtual Academy course: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/deep-dive-into-azure-app-service-a-platform-to-build-modern-applications-16828?l=vIBh1KR4C_8504668937 This material was recorded by the folks that work on App Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have multiple apps that I want to run under the same domain and the url to be applied as such.

Per my understanding, you could configure multiple virtual directories and applications within a single Azure website. You could follow the steps below:

- Set up the Virtual Directory or Application

  Log into Azure Portal, choose your web app, click "SETTINGS > Application settings" and add the following configuration:

  [image]
- Deploy your application to Azure

  You could use [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or other tools (e.g. FTP, etc.) for deploying your application.

  [image]

**Test:**

[image]
[image]

Additionally, here is a [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) about deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website, you could refer to it.

**UPDATE:**

I checked the Environment variables about APP_POOL_ID via kudu:
`https://{your-appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml` and remote to my azure web app using [IIS Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/), and found the following settings:

[image]

For adding your custom domain for your azure web app, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: I do believe this is what I am looking for.  Will they run via seperate different app pools?  I currently have the app as one using areas within an mvc application.  I want to separate them as separate apps and assure that they will run as separate apps as well.  Another thing.  I want my own domain name and not an azurewebsite.net domain.  I am pretty sure I can do this but can you validate this?

Comment: I updated my answer for explanation, you could refer to it.

Comment: So I knew that you could do what I want to do with IIS.  I did not know that you have IIS exposure with Azure App Services to do this.  I know that if I go virtual server then I have all the abilities I need but I do not want to manage a server.  I am looking for how I can do this in App Services.

Comment: Per my understanding, you could either create two web apps with the custom domains (e.g. `app1.mysite.com` ——> `app1.azurewebsites.net`, `app2.mysite.com`——> `app2.azurewebsites.net`) or create a web app with the custom domain (`mysite.com`) then add url rewirte rules and rewirte url from `mysite.com/(app1|app2)` to `(app1|app2).azurewebsites.net`, then you could separate your apps into totally separate apps and they would run under the different app pools.

Answer (score 0):

Add them in separate directories instead of root directories. When you add them in the root directories the app starts from mysite.com. But if you add them into different directories then it starts as mysite.com/dir1 and mysite.com/dir2